# How to add links in angular js with dynamic output

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller, directive

I have page say categories here I'm loading categories from my api request 
on clicking first category I need to load some other page say products and need to load products from some other api. 
When I am linking it with simple href it displays

`{{ product.productname }}`

MyController page :

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-categories")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.categories = response.categories;});
});
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.id = 2; 
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-products?id=id")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.products = response.categories;});
});
```

My index page :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" ng-controller="CategoryController">
            <ul class="cat" ng-repeat="x in categories">
            <li>
                <a href="list.html/{{x.id }}"> {{ x.name }} </a>
            </li>
            </ul>  
        </div>
        </body>
```

my listpage :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" ng-controller="ProductController">
            <ul class="cat" ng-repeat="pdts in products">
            <li>
                {{ pdts.productname }}
            </li>
            </ul>  
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: ** MyController page : **
 

   ` var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-categories")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.categories = response.categories;});
});
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.id = 2; 
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-products?id=id")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.products = response.categories;});
});   `

Comment: I suggest you thoroughly go through the [official AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to gain a basic understanding of how Angular works. E.g. you should not have two `<body>` tags with the `ng-app` directive twice.

Comment: isn't this should like this: `$http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-products?id="+id)` and frankly speaking agreed with **muenchdo**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:-

```
1) you can use $state.go() and pass id parameters to products state.

2) you can use $cookiestore and set the id in the cookie and later retrieve in the products state.



var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('products',{
           url: '/products/:ID',
           title: 'productlist',
           templateUrl: 'app/views/product/productlist.html',
           controller:'productlistController'
        })
   }]);



app.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $http ,$state) {

        $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-categories")
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.categories = response.categories;
        });

        $scope.redirectTo = function(id){
           $state.go('products', {ID : id});
        };

   });



app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http , $state) {
        var id = $state.params.ID;
        $http.get("http://192.168.1.112/estore/api/get-products?id="+id)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.products = response.products;
        });
   });
```

INDEX PAGE

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div role="main" class="ui-content" ng-controller="CategoryController">
     <ul class="cat" ng-repeat="x in categories">
     <li>
          <a ng-click="redirectTo(x.id)"> {{ x.name }} </a>
     </li>
     </ul>  
</div>
</body>
```